# php - include html pages outside the root folder

Tags: php, html, include

On my php site I'm trying to include html pages outside the root folder (the html pages change automatically)

if I include an html page I get the 404 error for the linked files and if I include the linked files too they aren't displayed correctly

**path/site/root/index.php**

```
...
include("path/html/index1.html");
include("path/html/index1_files/img.png");
...
```

**path/html/index1.html**

```
...
<img src="index1_files/img.png">
...
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the directory properly. So, in your case, when linking to the image, replace `<img src="index1_files/img.png">` with `<img src="./index1_files/img.png">`. The `./` goes back into the folder the file is saved in, and ../ goes up one level. Your code is looking for a folder called index1_files within the current page.

Comment: `../` goes back one level, `./` is the current folder

Comment: @Yankue Team since the html pages change automatically is there another way to do that without having to find and replace paths periodically?

Comment: @Miky you can type the URL instead, so either HTTPS://..... or localhost/.....

Comment: ok but the reason I include them in php is because I want to keep them private so that they can't be reached with a public url